# Finding a perfect matching that include $e_{1}$ and exclude $e_{2}$ in a connected bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

Let $G$ be a $k$-regular bipartite graph with $k\ge3$, and $e_{1},e_{2}$
be edges of $G$. Show that if $G-\{e_{1},e_{2}\}$ is connected,
then there exist a perfect matching in $G$ that includes $e_{1}$
but not $e_{2}$.

I have been able to demonstrate that there exists a perfect matching
that includes $e_{1}$ and that there exists another perfect matching that does not includes $e_{2}$ using Hall's theorem. However, I cannot find a single matching that
satisfies both conditions at the same time.

I appreciate any hints.

Comment: Take your matching that includes $e_1$ and try to modify it to find one not containing $e_2$.